# Query for a latest updateTime for specific user

Tags: sql

I have a table that a user placing bets on `dUpdateTime`.

DB Table ：
[image]

[image]

My Query :

```
select * from tbet where iUserKey=53298
```

How do I create a query that would give me the latest `dUpdateTime` with `iUserKey = 53298`.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`MAX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) aggregate function

```
SELECT MAX(dUpdateTime) FROM tbet WHERE iUserKey = 53298
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from tbet where iUserKey=53298 order by dUpdateTime desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use max aggregate function to get the latest

```
SELECT MAX(dUpdateTime) FROM tbet WHERE iUserKey=53298
```